# SWT Shell KeyListener

Tags: java, javafx, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

#### 1.) The Goal

The file quick preview widget of OSX. Basically, on Mac, when you select a file and press the spacebar, you get a quick preview of that file. I'm trying to replicate that functionality with SWT+JFace (mmmaybe JavaFX).

This would be a `Shell` for me.

[image: Mac screenshot of the quick preview]

---

#### 2.) The Specifics

- The preview widget will be a `APPLICATION_MODAL` `Shell` attached to a `StructuredViewer`.
- I do not want to recreate the `Shell` each time I open the preview. I just want it hidden. This is supposed to be a **quick** preview.
- I want to be able to close this `Shell` on <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.
- I process many types of files (PDF, JPEG, PNG, TXT etc.), so each file has it's own preview component. The `Shell` knows how to switch between these components.
- This component **may not** modify any files, just preview them. The components I used to construct the previews is another story.

---

#### 3.) The Problems

- Since the `Shell` has direct children, those children may 'steal' the focus and grab the `KeyEvent`s. Thus, the `Shell` doesn't know how to close on keyboard events.
- I do not want to add `Display` filters. I would have to add/remove them each time I show/hide the `Shell`. Plus, those are very dangerous, because it's a huge RCP application, and it may affect other workbench parts (if the filters aren't removed for some reason).

---

#### 4.) SSCCE

In the following example, you can observe that once the `Text` has focus, the `Shell` cannot grab back the focus, and key events aren't being pumped to it anymore.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class SSCCE_ShellWithShellParent
{

    // ==================== 1. Static Fields ========================

    private static final int CHILD_SHELL_STYLE = SWT.BORDER | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL;


    // ==================== 3. Static Methods ====================

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new SSCCE_ShellWithShellParent();
    }


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ====================

    private SSCCE_ShellWithShellParent()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final Shell childShell = new Shell(shell, CHILD_SHELL_STYLE);
        childShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        childShell.pack();

        createChildContents(childShell);

        final KeyAdapter keyListener = new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e)
            {
                final Object source = e.getSource();

                if (source == shell)
                    System.out.println(e.keyCode);
                else
                    System.err.println(e.keyCode);

                // Escape
                if (e.keyCode == 27)
                    shell.close();

                // Spacebar
                if (e.keyCode == 32 && e.getSource() == shell)
                    childShell.open();
            }
        };

        childShell.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        shell.addKeyListener(keyListener);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ====================

    private void createChildContents(final Shell childShell)
    {
        new Text(childShell, SWT.NULL);
    }

}
```

---

#### 5.) TL;DR

Add `KeyListener` on a `Shell` without using filters.

Comment: +1 Looking forward to a good answer here (if one exists). That's a huuuuge drop shadow btw...

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the **answer** for your **first** problem. You can:

- Remove the focus capacity from the shell's children with the method     `WHATEVER_CHILD.setFocusable(false);`
- Make the shell request focus each time it losts it, by adding a focuslistener:
  `YOUR_SHELL.addFocusListener(new FocusListener{
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
      YOUR_SHELL.requestFocusOnWindow();
     }
  });`

I personally prefer the second option.

Comment: `setFocusable(boolean)` and `requestFocusOnWindow()` do not exist in SWT